# create a new and unique file each time one function is compiled in java

Tags: java, file

create a new and unique file each time the function is compiled.
that means if file exists already before execution of the program 
then 
it should delete the file and create a new file and append the new data.
or 
add the content after just deleting the complete data which is already there in the same file.

I have created something like this....

```
Writer output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\" + bankAccNo + ".txt", true));
output.append(myRow.getCell(0).toString()+ "\n");
output.close();
```

Comment: every time a program is executed i want to create a new file with same name.

Comment: It is appending into the file each time these lines of code are being called.

but what I want is each time when the PROGRAM executes It creates a new file with same name.

Comment: Just do `file.delete()` on startup? I don't see how that would be complicated.

Comment: Thats because you are calling the append. Simply write to the stream directly, without appending.

Comment: What has your problem to do with "unique file each time the function is compiled"?  Please fix your your title and problem description. If you use the FileWrite Constructor `append=true` "then bytes will be written to the end of the file rather than the beginning"

Comment: @Vikas: because I want to append the data till program completely executes...
but before starting execution of these lines I want to delete the file which contains same name as the file name in the same directory....

Comment: @Abhinav as long as our output stream is open the data will be appended to the file / output. 'append=true' in the FileWriter constructor controlls whether the next bytes written to the output are written to the beginning of the file or appended at the end of the file.

Comment: I need to append the data each time i am writing using these lines of code but before start writing/creating this file, I want to check if this file already exists, then create a new file with some other name......

Answer (score 1):

If you want to overwrite the file contents every time you write to it, use `false` for the append switch.

```
new FileWriter("<file>", false);
```

Comment: U r right but i dont want that...

I need to append the data each time i am writing
but before start writing to this file i want to check if this file already exists then then create a new file with some other name......

Comment: @Abhinav if you want to overwrite your file each time you start your application / open the File `FileWriter("<file>", false);` is the correct choice ortherwise fix your problem description. You may also have a look at [File API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html)